# srand and decisions issue

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, srand

I'm totally new to C Progamming and I encountered some issues.

I'm trying to create a Word Search , however I encountered a problem. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_search

I'm trying to randomize a number so the array that contains the words will be random .
The srand works before I add a decision or any other piece of coding.

I'm using the switch case because I had problems with the else if.

This is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10


int main (void)
{

    int r;

    srand(time(NULL));

    r = (rand() % 3) + 1 ; //random number

    printf ("%d\n", r);

    char *names1[]= {"DOG" , "CAT", "HORSE" , "SNAKE" };
    char *names2[]= {"RAT", "FOX", "FISH", "DRAGON" };
    char *names3[]= { "TIGER", "COW", "SHARK", "BEAR" };


    switch(r)
    {
    case '1' : printf (" %s", names1); 
        break;

    case '2' : printf (" %s", names2); 
        break;

    case '3' : printf (" %s", names3); 
        break;

    default : puts ("Invalid");



   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: `'1'` is very different than `1`.

Comment: Look as though you need to call `rand()` twice: once to pick which set of animals, again to select the animal within that. So `rand() % 3` and then `rand() % 4`. Stick with 0-based values, only adjust 0->1 for human consumption.

Comment: I only need to pick the set of animals therefore I think I need to call rand() only once.

The problem I'm encountering is that the program doesn't even compile.

Comment: You lack a closing brace to end the `switch` statement.  You have to use integer literals (`case 1:`) and not character literals (`case '1':`) in your switch, as the result of your random expression is an integer, not a character (the character literal `'1'` has a different value than the integer literal `1`)  You cannot print `names1` with a format `"%s"` because it is an array of strings (and not a simple string)  you have to decide if you print `names1[0]`, or which index you want to use (perhaps another random call can help here).

Answer (score 3):

`'1'` is not same `1`. Change your `case '1':` to `case 1:`

And

```
case '1' : printf (" %s", names1);
```

to

```
case 1 : printf (" %s", names1[r]);
```

Similar changes in other case statements.

Comment: I've replaced the '1' with a 1.

However I still get errors.
Undeclared identifiers for names1 etc

Missing ; before type

Comment: @Takan: Put all of your local declarations at the top of the function.

Comment: As noted by @Jongware, you may need to declare your variables at the beginning of the main() function. It could be that you are compiling in C89/C90 mode which requires variable declarations at the start of a *block.* In any case, posting the exact error messages would help a lot in figuring out the issue more easily.

Comment: I've updated the code. The follow errors are coming up:

1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fdf\fdf\program.c(16): warning C4013: 'srand' undefined; assuming extern returning int

1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fdf\fdf\program.c(18): warning C4013: 'rand' undefined; assuming extern returning int

1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fdf\fdf\program.c(74): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fdf\fdf\program.c(9)' was matched

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: I had a missing curly brackets. 

The code is working however only one animal from the list is printing.

Comment: As I mentioned in above comments, you need to select the animal within each list. Or a loop printing them all.

Comment: @Takari If you want to print one animal from *each* array then you probably don't need a switch case at all (since the `r` is calculated to be within the bounds of the array). See: http://ideone.com/FmAYyD  It all depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem. Thanks for all the answers. 
This is the fully working program for someone having the same problem.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10


int main (void)
{
 int l;
 int r;
 char *names1[]= {"DOG" , "CAT", "HORSE" , "SNAKE" };
 char *names2[]= {"RAT", "FOX", "FISH", "DRAGON" };
 char *names3[]= { "TIGER", "COW", "SHARK", "BEAR" };

 srand(time(NULL));

 r = (rand() % 3) + 1 ; //random number


 

 switch(r)
 {
 case 1 : 
   for (l = 0; l  <4; l++ )
 {
  printf (" %s", names1[l]);
  
 }
  break;

 case 2 : 
   for (l = 0; l  <4; l++ )
 {
  printf (" %s", names2[l]);
  
 }
  break;
 
 case 3 :  
   for (l = 0; l  <4; l++ )
 {
  printf (" %s", names3[l]);
  
 }
  break;

 default : puts ("Invalid");

 }

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```